# Can I force a quest objective to be complete with a console command?

Tags: mods, fallout-3

I am running Fallout 3 modded with the [Fallout Wanderers Edition](http://fallout3.nexusmods.com/mods/2761) mod. Until now everything has been perfect, but when I have completed ["The Waters of Life"](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Waters_of_Life) quest until the routine maintenance part, I have become stuck.

There is a point when you have to install new fuses into the fuse control box. After that you're supposed to go up and activate the mainframe. But when I insert the fuses, the quest does not advance to the next objective. The "Replace damaged fuses" objective stays incomplete, but I can not activate the fuse control box again, nor can I open the mainframe door (nor activate the mainframe, I have tried going into the room with clipping turned off).

Is there a way to force this objective to be complete so that I can continue to the next one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using the command `setstage <quest ID> <stage ID>`. In your case, the quest ID is 00014e8b, the current stage is 55 and the desired stage is 60 (The Wikia article you've linked lists the stages and their IDs). The exact command you want is `setstage 00014e8b 60`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the command I've been looking for, but I couldn't check whether that would have helped me. After restarting the game everything went to normal all by itself.

Comment: I believe you don't need leading zeros (at least you don't in oblivion/skyrim) and the scripting engines are all based on each other.

Comment: @ewanm89 that's right, leading zeroes are optional.

Comment: Iirc in one of these games (fallout oblivion etc all run on a similar engine) it is not possible to reopen a quest after it has been completed, so do be careful with that.